# How to Create a Custom Facet with Hierarchy in Sitecore 9?

Tags: xdb, xconnect, experience-analytics, experience-profile, contact-facets

I would like to create some form of a hierarchy in a `Custom Facet in Sitecore 9`. However, the documentation only provided examples using
 Sitecore 8.2 [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/create-a-custom-contact-facet.html).

When I tried creating an IElementDictionary in my custom Facet, it says `Facet` is an ambiguous reference between `Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Framework.Facet` and `Sitecore.XConnect.Facet`. Of course, this is due to the former being deprecated. My ModelBuilder also expects an XConnect.Facet in the modelBuilder.DefineFacet method to create the JSON model:

```
using Caiw.Foundation.XConnect.Models.Facets.Interfaces;
using Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Framework;
using Sitecore.XConnect;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Caiw.Foundation.Xconnect.Models.Facets
{
    [Serializable]
    [FacetKey(DefaultFacetKey)]
    public class ServiceabilityData : Facet
    {
        public const string DefaultFacetKey = "ServiceabilityData";

        public int HouseNumber { get; set; }

        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

        public string Addition { get; set; }

        public string LocationDescription { get; set; }

        public IElementDictionary<IInfrastructure> Infrastructure { get; }

        public string Street { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }

        public string Region { get; set; }

        public string Country { get; set; }

        public string OrderEndpointType { get; set; }

        public int CustomerGroup { get; set; }

        public ServiceabilityData() { }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here? How do we extend a hierarchical Facet in Sitecore 9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to create facets containing `Dictionary<K,V>` or `List<T>` properties in 9.1. Facet class needs to derive from `Sitecore.XConnect.Facet`. See Sitecore's [documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/create-a-custom-facet.html) for more information.
Here's a sample facet class taken from XConnect's core model:

```
  [FacetKey("Addresses")]
  [Serializable]
  public class AddressList : Sitecore.XConnect.Facet
  {
    public const string DefaultFacetKey = "Addresses";

    public AddressList(Address preferredAddress, string preferredKey)
    {
      this.PreferredAddress = preferredAddress;
      this.PreferredKey = preferredKey;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, Address> Others { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, Address>();

    public string PreferredKey { get; set; }

    public Address PreferredAddress { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I realized this when I saw that AddressList and Emails could be multiple entries as specified in this schema: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/image/15d074b33c7e74.png

Answer (score 1):

Your class `ServiceabilityData` must be inherits `Sitecore.XConnect.Facet`. Below is the code:

```
using Sitecore.XConnect;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Caiw.Foundation.Xconnect.Models.Facets
{
    [Serializable]
    [FacetKey(DefaultFacetKey)]
    public class ServiceabilityData : Facet
    {
        public const string DefaultFacetKey = "ServiceabilityData";
        public int HouseNumber { get; set; }

        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

        public string Addition { get; set; }

        public string LocationDescription { get; set; }

        //public IElementDictionary<IInfrastructure> Infrastructure { get; }

        public string Street { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }

        public string Region { get; set; }

        public string Country { get; set; }

        public string OrderEndpointType { get; set; }

        public int CustomerGroup { get; set; }
        public static explicit operator ServiceabilityData(KeyValuePair<string, Facet> v)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes this is useful when I am about to use the ServiceabilityData as like a Dictionary I think, but the Dictionary property inside this class is what I needed. Thanks for the response!